# Distal features of wh-words cross-linguistically

Tags: cross-linguistic, questions

My question concerns distal marking on Wh-words. Pronouns like 'this'/'here' and 'that'/'there' show clear marking of the proximal/distal distinction. Wh-words seem to exhibit some similarities to pronouns in certain contexts, so I was wondering if there might be any cases cross-linguistically of wh-words being marked at all for this distinction.

Comment: Nice question! And welcome to Linguistics SE.

Comment: Since you're talking about relative and interrogative pronouns (I assume; "wh-word" is uncross-linguistic), they're all going to be indefinite (interrogative), or else they're going to appear with an antecedent NP (relative). Proximal/distal seems to be a mismatch for these words; why would one use them, and what would they mean? Oh, and while I think of it, what about 1-2-3 demonstrative systems like Spanish _este, ese, aquello_? They don't show up on "qu-words", either.

Comment: wh-words ARE pronouns, not only "similar" to them, lol.

Comment: @Anixx - _Where_ and _when_ are not pronouns, they are adverbs.